# What different between store database in different locations in iOS?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite.swift

I'm working with SQLite.swift.
In the document, the path to the database is:

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true
                ).first!
```

but i want to import and use an existing database, so i've dragged my existing database to my keyboard extension folder, and create connection to it with path is:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("db", ofType:"sqlite3")
```

So, i've noticed that the first way, the database will be store in `/Users/*/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B1DB861-AA3F-446F-A559-D4727CDB9285/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/0BC647E4-26F3-4A1F-8271-CC73C96FD197/Documents`

and the second way, the database will be store in the app.

```
/Users/*/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B1DB861-AA3F-446F-A559-D4727CDB9285/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E5D9514C-859A-4D4D-A771-A8CE9CDCD3E7/AppName.app/PlugIns/AppNameExt.appex
```

What's different between these two locations?
The second way might increase the app size because it contains the database?
And if i want to Archive/Submit my App to the AppStore with existing database, is this the only way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference is that storing the file in the documents folder means you can write (update) it, which is pretty important for a database file.  You cannot write to a file in the app bundle.

The usual pattern for using a database in an app is:

1. Create a pre-seeded database during development and copy it to the app bundle during building.
2. When running, check if the database file exists and is up-to-date in the documents folder.
3. If not, copy it from the app bundle.
4. Open the database in the documents folder and read/write as desired.

Comment: So, do you say that we can't write / update database if i store it in the app bundle? I've tested on the simulator and i still can update the existing database (which is stored in the app bundle). And with the usual pattern for using database, the first step i've done correctly, right? I've dragged the db file to keyboard ext folder (Copy Bundle Resources), and after that, when running, the app will create the connection to this database and use it?

Comment: No you can't write to a file in the app bundle.  You can on the simulator but not on a real device.  Yeah that sounds OK.

Comment: How exactly should i do with the Step 2? can you give me a sample code?

Comment: @TomSawyer No I can't.