# iOS: How to copy pre-seeded database at the first running app with SQLite.swift to writeable location?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I had the previous question here about database location.
[What different between store database in different locations in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609746/what-different-between-store-database-in-different-locations-in-ios)

I'm confused in copying pre-seeded database to the writable location.

Now, every time I run and build my app, the in-use database will be replaced by pre-seeded db.

And in the future, if I update my app version, how do I prevent the database from being replaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I prevent the database from being replaced?

Check the destination before you copy the database. If there's already a file there, don't do the copy. You can use `-[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:]` to check for an existing file.

Comment: And how to copy db from Copy Bundle Resources to the DocumentDirectory?

Comment: You don't copy from "Copy Bundle resources"... that's a build step. You should have a database file that's listed in Copy Bundle Resources -- that's how it gets into the app when you build it. When the app runs, you check if the file already exists, and if it doesn't use a method like `NSFileManager`'s `-copyItemAtPath:toPath:` to copy the file to the documents directory.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm working with swift. Here is my code: `do {
                try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(orgpath!, toPath: dbpath as String)
                
                ConnectToDB()
                
            } catch let error as NSError {
               print(error)
            }` but i afraid that `ConnectToDB()` method will be call before `copyItemAtPath` finished?

Comment: Has that actually been a problem?

Comment: i want to ask if the db file is large, will it wait until `copyItemAtPath` complete and execute the next method ( `ConnectToDb()` ) after? and what happens if user delete the app / reinstall / or update? will the data be lost?

Comment: User deletes app -> all the app's data on the device is also removed. And yes, [`copyItemAtPath(...)` is a synchronous operation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH6-SW10), so it won't return until the operation is complete.